# JS This and Template Literals Practice

Tags: javascript, this, template-literals

Hi I can't get a background image to appear within the box in the middle on top, when hovering the other three boxes below.  Right now only the text appears.  Thanks for any help you can provide.  PLEASE let me know if you need more clarification.

I believe this is the problem code:

```
 document.getElementById('message').style.backgroundImage = `"url('${element.src}')";`;
        console.log(`"url('${element.src}')";`);
}
```

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/vaughnick/pen/VygjZw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the quotes around `url()`.

```
document.getElementById('message').style.backgroundImage = `url('${element.src}')`;
//                                                         ^                     ^ without
//                                                                                 "
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this   `"url('${element.src}')"`;
do it like this `url(${element.src})`;

```js
function showProperties(element){
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = element.alt;
          document.getElementById('message').style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.src});`;
        console.log(`url(${element.src})`);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#message{
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
  width: 575px;
    height: 100px;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
  width:10%;
  margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<h1> This and Template Literals</h1>
 <div id = "message">
  Hover over an image to display the alt text.
 </div>
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "showProperties(this)" onmouseleave = "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "showProperties(this)" onmouseleave =  "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">
 
 <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "showProperties(this)" onmouseleave =  "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">
```

Comment: Thanks, is that working for you? I must not have done it right in codepen or my editor. https://codepen.io/vaughnick/pen/VygjZw

Comment: awesome, thank you. combined with ninas help it is now fixed... your solution just needed the quotes within the parentheses i think